# Can a property of a class be the class itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, properties, self-reference

Can a class have a property and the class of the property is the class itself?

```
@interface testClass:NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) testClass *testProperty;
@end

@implementation testClass
@end
```

Comment: Just 3 characters to answer this post.. "YES"

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes it can have, this is called self-referencing class.**

Why it is not a compiler issue ?

Because you create a pointer to the object of same type, not the object.

This is frequently seen in C / C++ data structures like Linked List.

Comment: @Hancock_Xu: One sidenote: Always follow naming conventions... ClassName should be CamelCase as `TestClass`